# Getting a build error when installing a NGiNX eval module

Tags: nginx

Here is the module I am unable to install:

http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/eval.en.html

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
/root/src/nginx_eval_module-1.0.1/ngx_http_eval_module.c: In function ‘ngx_http_eval_block’:
/root/src/nginx_eval_module-1.0.1/ngx_http_eval_module.c:531:39: error: variable ‘pclcf’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
/root/src/nginx_eval_module-1.0.1/ngx_http_eval_module.c:522:32: error: variable ‘ecf’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [objs/addon/nginx_eval_module-1.0.1/ngx_http_eval_module.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/src/nginx-1.2.7'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

./configure

```
./configure --user=nginx --group=nginx --prefix=/usr/local/nginx-1.2.7 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_addition_module --without-mail_pop3_module --without-mail_imap_module --without-mail_smtp_module --with-pcre-jit --add-module=/root/src/nginx-upload-module-2.2m --add-module=/root/src/nginx-upload-progress-module --with-http_stub_status_module --add-module=/root/src/ngx_http_php_session --add-module=/root/src/ngx_http_redis-0.3.6 --add-module=/root/src/echo-nginx-module --add-module=/root/src/nginx_eval_module-1.0.1
```

My version of NGiNX is 1.2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings looks not critical, so it should be safe to remove "-Werror" from your compiler options and try again.

Comment: How do I remove the -Werror? And what is causing it?

Comment: it should be somewhere inside the makefile - usually set in a variable named "CFLAGS". the cause for the warnings is: bad code

Comment: In my nginx 1.4.1 it is located in objs/Makefile and then defined in the 2nd line - just remove -Werror and try again.

Comment: Weird. Every time I remove -Werror from objs/Makefile and then do the make command it comes back... Why? Is there another way?

Comment: Solved it. You just need to remove the -Werror but only after ./configure was set. Because that command will re-create the Makefile. And then just do the make && make install command.